# Visual state of checkbox is not updating while value is set

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, cordova

I have following problem in code below:

https://jsfiddle.net/ftnLv0pm/

I run widget on cordova.js in android application and I have a problem that visual state of view-standard-card-is-active-checkbox is not updating in widget, while its data is updated while it is working on web (i have checked it few times).
Is there any way to force update visual state of switch? Or maybe there is an error in my code.

```
var cardEnabledCheckboxInput = $('#view-standard-card-is-active-checkbox');
var cardEnabledCheckbox = $('#view-standard-card-is-active-label');

if (currentCardData) {
            // This does not updates visual state, while has true inside
            cardEnabledCheckboxInput.prop('checked', currentCardData.enabled);

            // default card switch needs to be hidden if the card is disabled.
            if (!currentCardData.enabled) {
                hideDefaultCardSwitch();
            }
        }
```

That code is just does no effect on visual state.

var currentCardData is json that contains data about card.

Comment: a bit more of your code wouldn't hurt

Comment: @yark1y what is `currentCardData`? @AndroidSmoker74 LOL

Comment: @plonknimbuzz i explained a bit about it in my post. `currentCardData.enabled` is always true in current implementation. So it is the same as I write true there, and `if (currentCardData) {}` is accessed all the time, I can guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're just updating your data. you have to update the view where data changes as well.
If you're doing this from another class make sure you run this command on UI thread.

Comment: Anything i can read about that? I'm just a bit confused, thought that if checkbox is checked ui has to update itself.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#view-standard-card-is-active-checkbox').prop('checked', true);

$(document).ready(function() {
    //set initial state.
    $('#view-standard-card-is-active-checkbox').val($(this).is(':checked'));

    $('#view-standard-card-is-active-checkbox').change(function() {
        $('#view-standard-card-is-active-checkbox').val($(this).is(':checked'));
    });

    $('#view-standard-card-is-active-checkbox').click(function() {
        if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
            return confirm("Are you sure?");
        }else{
         return confirm("checked");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.view-standard-card-is-active-label {
    margin-top: 2%;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    right: 6.9%;
    background: #d5d5d5;
    border-radius: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.view-standard-card-is-active-label:after {
    margin-top: 2%;
    position: relative;
    left: -2px;
    top: -12px;
    display: block;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: #777777;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    content: '';
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.view-standard-card-is-active-label:active:after { transform: scale(1.15, 0.85); }

#view-standard-card-is-active-checkbox:checked ~ .view-standard-card-is-active-label {
    background: #d5d5d5;
}

#view-standard-card-is-active-checkbox:checked ~ .view-standard-card-is-active-label:after {
    left: 20px;
    background: #ff0000;
}

#view-standard-card-is-active-checkbox:disabled ~ .view-standard-card-is-active-label {
    background: #F6F6F6;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#view-standard-card-is-active-checkbox:disabled ~ .view-standard-card-is-active-label:after { background: #bcbdbc; }
```

```html
<input id="view-standard-card-is-active-checkbox" type="checkbox" class="checkbox hidden"/>
<label for="view-standard-card-is-active-checkbox" id="view-standard-card-is-active-label" class="view-standard-card-is-active-label"></label>
```